# Setting bits on Arduino freeRTOS

Tags: c, arduino, freertos

I have been studying freeRTOS on Arduino, and I made some code, as it follows
So I got this Arduino RTOS code

```
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>
#include "event_groups.h"

#define red    6
#define Yellow 7
#define blue   8

#define TASK1_BIT (1UL<<0UL) //Unsigned long bit0 set to 1
#define TASK2_BIT (1UL<<1U)

EventGroupHandle_t xEventGroup;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(red,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue,OUTPUT);

  xEventGroup = xEventGroupCreate();

  xTaskCreate(EventBitSettingTask,"Bit Setter",100,NULL,1,NULL);
  xTaskCreate(EventBitReadingTask,"Bit Reader",100,NULL,1,NULL);
}


void EventBitSettingTask(void *pvParameters)
{
  const TickType_t xDelay500ms = pdMS_TO_TICKS(500);
  while(1)
  {
    xEventGroupSetBits(xEventGroup,TASK1_BIT); //Event,bit
    vTaskDelay(xDelay500ms);
    xEventGroupSetBits(xEventGroup,TASK2_BIT);
  }
}


void EventBitReadingTask(void *pvParameters)
{
  const EventBits_t xBitsToWaitFor = (TASK1_BIT | TASK2_BIT);
  EventBits_t xEventGroupValue;
  
  while(1)
  {
    xEventGroupValue = xEventGroupWaitBits(xEventGroup,xBitsToWaitFor,pdTRUE,pdTRUE,portMAX_DELAY);//EventGroup,receive, clear on exit, all bits?,wait
    
    if(xEventGroupValue & TASK1_BIT != 0)
    {
      digitalWrite(red,digitalRead(red)^1);
    }
    
    if(xEventGroupValue & TASK2_BIT != 0)
    {
      digitalWrite(blue,digitalRead(blue)^1);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {


}
```

While playing with it, I realized if I set `TASK1_BIT (1UL<<0UL)` to `TASK1_BIT (0UL<<0UL)`, none of the leds will blink, but if I set `TASK2_BIT (1UL<<1UL)` to `TASK2_BIT (0UL<<1UL)`, just the red led will blink.

Apparently, the event of the blue led is dependent from the event of the red led, but why???

Comment: Not sure how `xEventGroupSetBits` works, but I'd assume if you provide 0 (0 shifted by whatever remains 0!) it would clear out all bits. If so, then as you don't have any delay in between setting TASK_BIT2 and TASK_BIT1 the blue led just doesn't get any time to light up. If I'm right adding a delay before setting TASK_BIT1 should make the blue led blink as well.

Comment: Minor fix for above assumption: As the *other* task controls the LED: Most likely the bit is already reset to 0 before the other task gets a chance to read it having been set to 1. Timing behaviour remains, though (-> add another delay).

Answer (score 0):

According to the FreeRTOS documentation, `xEventGroupWaitBits()` is used to read the value of an event group and optionally wait in the blocked state for one or more event bits in the event group to become set.

The parameter `xBitsToWaitFor` specifies which event bits in the event group will be tested. If the parameter `xWaitForAllBits` is set to pdTRUE, bitwise AND will be used in the test. Setting `xTicksToWait` to portMAX_DELAY will cause the task to wait without timing out. That means the task will leave a blocked state only when unblock condition is met.

When TASK1_BIT and TASK2_BIT are set to 0001 and 0010 respectively (in binary), the event group will leave the blocked state only when all the bits in the event group are equal to `xWaitForAllBits`, in this case 0011. That will happen after two calls to `xEventGroupSetBits()`.

After the event group leaves the blocked state, the value of each bit in the group will be compared to bit's default value, and if the particular bit was set, the led will blink. So by default, both leds should blink intermittently.

If you change the value of TASK1_BIT to 0 (by 0UL<<0UL), than the value of `xBitsToWaitFor` will be 0010. The result of `xEventGroupValue & TASK1_BIT` (0010 & 0000) will be 0 so the red led won't blink. On the other hand, the result of `xEventGroupValue & TASK2_BIT` (0010 & 0010) will be != 0 so the blue led should blink.

Vice versa, if you set the value of TASK2_BIT to 0 (by 0UL<<1UL), than the value of `xBitsToWaitFor` will be 0001. `xEventGroupValue & TASK1_BIT` (0001 & 0001) will return 1 and the red led will blink. `xEventGroupValue & TASK2_BIT` (0001 & 0000) will return 0 so the blue led shouldn't blink.

A detailed explanation of how these API-s work can be found at https://freertos.org.

Comment: that is what I thought would happen, however, as stated above, is I set TASK1_BIT to 0, no led blinks at all.

Comment: Try adding the parantheses for bitwise AND test in `if(xEventGroupValue & TASK1_BIT != 0)` and `if(xEventGroupValue & TASK2_BIT != 0)`. Bitwise AND has lower precedence than inequality operator !=.

Comment: To explain the above, in the test (0010 & 0010 != 0) first 0010 != 0 gets evaluated and the result is 1. Than 0010 & 1 is evaluated and the result is 0. So the test fails and the led doesn't blink. Putting the parentheses should fix this.

Comment: Well, that previous comment is the actual answer... Good catch, didn't notice the missing parentheses myself. Once more that precedence decision proves unfortunate (historically grown, I know...).